# Cocoa Touch UITabBar action on tab switch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` with a number of `UITabBarItem`s. I've assigned a different view controller to each of these.

I want to load some data etc., when each button is clicked. Therefore I will like to know where to put that code? I tried implementing `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` in the view controller but those didn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your custom controllers inherit from UIViewController?

Don't forget the signature for the viewWillAppear is `viewWillAppear:animated:`

I'm working off the beta 5 right now, and it works just fine (I'm also using a TabBar).

Answer (score 2):

I know that when you assign a delegate to a `UINavigationController`, the component `UIViewController` delegate methods are not called. It seems likely that the same is true of `UITabBarController`.

I would try implementing the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and implementing the `tabBar:didSelectViewController:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in viewdidappear function.but i didn't try